# tramp ssh: Waiting for prompts from remote shell

Tags: emacs, tramp

I have been using emacs with tramp for a few weeks now to ssh into a server and edit some files. I do this by `C-x C-f /ssh:username@server.com`. Suddenly this has stopped working. I am getting "Waiting for prompts from remote shell problem" message.

However, If I don't provide a username (`C-x C-f /ssh:server.com`) then the connection seems to get established.

I am running emacs 24 using cygwin. How can I get this connection to work again?

Comment: This can't be answered in general, too many possible options. Pls apply `(setq tramp-verbods 6)` and rerun your test. There will be a debug Tramp buffer. Send a bug report via `M-x tramp-bug`.

Comment: The problem seems to have disappeared, but I will follow those steps should they reappear.

Comment: I problem had haunted me for weeks, until I found that some times when you end the *tramp* session, the corresponding *ssh* process is not ended, blocking the communication channel. Just kill the zombie *ssh*.

Answer (score 1):

There is one relatively common reason (at least on **Windows/Cygwin** platform): the ssh process started by tramp gets somehow stuck and unresponsive.
On my current desktop this happens once every month or so.

Just kill any ssh processes, either from your favourite cygwin terminal (with `kill -9`) or from your Windows task manager. This gets everything working again.

I have never encountered this problem on Linux, only on Windows/Cygwin.